# JSON Multi dimensional Array to Java Multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: java, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I am trying to convert a JSONArray whose String format is multi-dimensional to a Java multi-dimensional array. I have tried a lot of ways by myself and am getting lost in my task. Hopefully someone here can bring some clarity. Converting to a normal array is fine. But when I try to extend myself to a multi-dimensional I can't.

```
    public static final String stationData[][] = {
    // Station Names
            { "The Point", "Spencer Dock", "Mayor Square - NCI",
                    "George's Dock", "Bus Aras", "Connolly", "Brides Glen",
                    "Cherrywood", "Laughanstown", "Carrickmines" },
            // Station Url Fragments
            { "The%20Point", "Spencer%20Dock", "Mayor%20Square%20-%20NCI",
                    "George%27s%20Dock", "Bus%26aacute%3Bras", "Connolly",
                    "Brides%20Glen", "Cherrywood", "Laughanstown",
                    "Carrickmines"}
     };
```

`JSONArray myArray = (JSONArray) JSONSerializer.toJSON(stationData);`

I am just playing around with this array to see if I can get it to work. So at this point in my code can anyone tell me how to: from the JSONArray I have re-create the java multi-dimensional array it was created by?

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I know the question is specifically relating to JSON -> Java arrays; maybe there's a general case here, but why don't you use a URL encoding function instead of this kind of mapping? Or maybe there's something in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library that will help.

Comment: I might look into it. Been trying this way for awhile so I would ideally like to see it through but I may eventually attempt these methods thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my problem was pretty trivial. I was concerned that I was not able to do this with say 1 or 2 lines of code and I pretty much had to fill the array with data manually. Here's how I did it anyway.

```
        JSONArray myArray = (JSONArray) JSONSerializer.toJSON(stationData);
    //Slightly hard coded here.
    String[][] test = new String[myArray.getJSONArray(0).size()][myArray.getJSONArray(1).size()];

    for(int i = 0; i < myArray.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < myArray.getJSONArray(i).size(); j++){
            test[i][j] = (String) myArray.getJSONArray(i).get(j);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this:

```
public static final String stationData[][] = {
   { "The Point",  "The%20Point"},
   {"Spencer Dock", "Spencer%20Dock"},
   {"Mayor Square - NCI","Mayor%20Square%20-%20NCI"},
   {"George's Dock", "George%27s%20Dock"}
 };
```

Comment: No sorry I need the code that will convert my JSONArray which is multi-dimensional back to Java. Thanks tho.

Comment: So, what is that you have? An object from a third party library?

Comment: Yes that is what I am intending to achieve. For now I am just trying to get comfortable in converting the array.