# How to send 2 dimensional array from php to android

Tags: php, android, json, parsing

i want to send result proccess in php to android then i want to display the result in emulator..

but i cant send the result from php to android cz the result is an array 2Dimension

```
1      2        3
4      5        6
7      8        9
10    11       12
```

how to parse the result in android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) in PHP, and then decode it in Android.

Comment: I agree, JSON is the way to go

Comment: i do but it just works in 1D array, can you find me example with 2Dimension array?

Comment: @akalucas, in 2D? how to store in android?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250972/json-multi-dimensional-array-to-java-multi-dimensional-array

Answer (score 0):

JSon is a good way, and this is an example
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/4692780/719212
or http://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/connection-between-php-server-and-android-client-using-http-and-json/

And for 2D array: [2D arrays in JSON getting converted into a 1D array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397772/2d-arrays-in-json-getting-converted-into-a-1d-array-of-objects)